# ERROR CONNECTING TO SQL SERVER 2014 WITH NETBEANS SSL TLS10 [TLS12]

Tags: java

**

**This is the connection path**
**

1. SQL SERVER 2014
2. JDK 11 JAVA
3. NETBEANS

**

```
    private String url ="jdbc:sqlserver://SAUL:1433;databaseName=prueba";
    private String login = "dev";
    private String password = "123456";
    private String driver = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver";
    Connection conn = null;

    public BDConnection() {
    }

    public Connection EstablecerConexion() {
        try {
            Class.forName(driver);
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,
                    login, password);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return conn;
    }
```

This is the problem that is displayed when running the program

**com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server with Secure Sockets Layer encryption (SSL). Error: "The server selected protocol version TLS10 is not accepted by client preferences [TLS12]"**. ClientConnectionId:ba132bbf-7f8c-47c6-9892-b7901f8e8b75
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.terminate(SQLServerConnection.java:2400)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.enableSSL(IOBuffer.java:1762)
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:1459)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:773)
at javaapplication2.JavaApplication2.main(JavaApplication2.java:19)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: The server selected protocol version TLS10 is not accepted by client preferences [TLS12]

Comment: Fix the all-caps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to update your SQL server instance and enable TLS 1.2, please follow this [link](https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/Error-The-Server-Selected-Protocol-Version-TLS10-Is-Not-Accepted-by-Client-Preferences-TLS12-After-Upgrading-To-OpenJDK8u292)